# Twig blank page ( using 3 templates model and inheritance mechanism)

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm following a tutorial about symfony2 framework ..

---

I've already managed to render a template which inherits from the base layout as follows

```
# ::layout.html.twig > MyvendorBlogBundle:blog:index.html.twig
# then inside the controller action, call
$this->render('MyvendorBlogBundle:Blog:index.html.twig', ['foo'=>'bar']);
```

---

I decided to add an intermediate template in between but I'm having trouble to make twig templating engine to render my 3 layouts cascaded templates: As mentioned above, i'm not able to get any output using the following schem but a blank page instead (no raised exceptions and the source only contains the base.html.twig code)

```
# ::layout.html.twig > MyvendorBlogBundle::layout.html.twig > MyvendorBlogBundle:blog:index.html.twig
```

Here are my templates

base (app/Ressources/views):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
    {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app-container">
            <header id="app-header">
            </header>
            <div id="app-page-content">
            {% block body %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}

        {# FLASH BAG HANDLING #}
        {% for label, flashes in app.session.flashbag.all %}
            {% for flash in flashes %}
                <div class="alert alert-{{ label }}">
                    {{ flash }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Then the blog bundle layout (src/Myvendor/BlogBundle/Resources/views):

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}
    {% block side %}
    <div id="blog-side">
        <nav>
            <a href="#">1rst link</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block main %}{% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

Now the index page template (src/Myvendor/BlogBundle/Resources/views/Blog):

```
{% extends "MyvendorBlogBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block main %}
    <h1>{{ caption }} !</h1>

    {% if caption is not empty %}
        {{ caption }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

And finally the controller

```
namespace Myvendor\BlogBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class BlogController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('MyvendorBlogBundle:Blog:index.html.twig', ['caption'=>'hello!']);
    }
}
```

May someone spot what's going on here ?
The pb maybe obvious but I've been stuck for a couple of hours now and blocks nesting seems perfect to me `:/`

Comment: Is your `index page template` really located in `src/Myvendor/BlogBundle/Resources/views` as you mentioned?

Comment: If so, you need to use `MyvendorBlogBundle::index.html.twig` instead of yours `MyvendorBlogBundle:Blog:index.html.twig`.

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov oups, copy/past problem `:s` Sorry the index final template is located here `src/Myvendor/BlogBundle/Resources/views/Blog` ... I going to edit my post, thanks. The pb still happening `:p` Thank you for the time you spent.

Comment: Did you clear cache? Your code looks fine.

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov I did, and actually removed files with root access to be sure there where no other breach somewhere else